# TeamCity Kotlin DSL - Use of function option in BuildType

Tags: teamcity, dsl

Does somebody knows how to use the function `option` in `BuildType` and how are then the options accessible?

Here the link to the function: https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/dsl-documentation/jetbrains.build-server.configs.kotlin.v2019_2/-build-type-settings/option.html

What's the intent behind this option? How is it then reflected inside a TeamCity Build Configuration?

Unfortunately, I haven't found a documentation / tutorial / post about that topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's relevant to the given [**Build Configuration Type**](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/dsl-documentation/jetbrains.build-server.configs.kotlin.v2018_1/-build-type/index.html) in any job.
This gives the default options:

- [Regular](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/deployment-build-configuration.html)
- [Composite](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/composite-build-configuration.html)
- [Deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/deployment-build-configuration.html)